# How to find the smoothest part of the trajectory using python?

Tags: python, opencv, video, computer-vision

I have came across the following problem. I have created a program that estimates the trajectory of camera recording video along x and y axis. This approach is very common in warp-stabilizers. I want to find the range of values which represent the most stable video footage and get their values. Here is the graph of trajectory. Graph is based on the numpy array. I guess that the best idea would be to pick up the part where the increase of values is the slowest but i am not sure how to do it.[image: Graph]

Comment: Do you want to know the most stable part for X and Y separately? And do you want to know the longest range of values that are stable upto a certain value, or a specific length of values that is as stable as possible?

Comment: Hello, yes both parts X and Y are important. I want to make sure that there is no extreme panning or tilting in the footage. I am only interested in the usable range of frames. But having a tool that will enable me just to figure out the most stable part of X or Y will do :) I would like to obtain as much of stable video a possible, the minimum is for me 25 frames.

Answer (score 1):

The following code will find the longest range of values that for both X and Y are stable for a certain threshold. This threshold limits the change in X and Y.
You can use it to tune your result.
If you want more stable section than choose epsilon lower.
This will result in a shorter range.

```
import numpy as np
X=150*np.random.rand(270) # mock data as I do not have yours
Y=150*np.random.rand(270) # Replace X and Y with your X and Y data

epsilon = 80 #threshold

# get indexes where the difference is smaller than the threshold for X and Y
valid_values = np.logical_and(np.abs(np.diff(X))<epsilon,np.abs(np.diff(Y))<epsilon)
cummulative_valid_values=[]
count = 0

# find longest range of values that satisfy the threshold
for id,value in enumerate(valid_values):
    if value == True:
        count=count+1
    else:
        count = 0
    cummulative_valid_values.append(count)

# Calculate start and end of largest stable range
end_of_range = cummulative_valid_values.index(max(cummulative_valid_values))+1
start_of_range = end_of_range-max(cummulative_valid_values)+1

print("Largest stable range is: ",start_of_range," - ",end_of_range)
```